# WPF Bitmap effect error on image source

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, effect

What I am trying to do is use the Imagebox as source for my bitmap effect and i dont know how to do that.My imagebox is called **image1** .

```
<Button Content="Blur" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,12,0,0"    Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Click="button3_Click" >
        <Image Source ="image1">
        <Image.BitmapEffect>
        <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="5" />
        </Image.BitmapEffect>
        </Image>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)? If not, I highly recommend using this pattern because WPF is built to use it and if you don't, you will fight it all the way.

Create a ViewModel class. Create a public property of type Image in this ViewModel class.

Create an instace of the ViewModel and put it into your Window's datacontext. Then add a binding to this property.

**Alternatively** for a quick fix (please note that this leads to darkness, you will regret having started to program this way):

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source, ElementName=image1}">
```

Edit:

Your edit is a completely different story: You have set the `Content` property twice: once by directly setting it and once by having a child object. Your button has both a text *and* an image as content. But a button (and most other controls) can only have *one* content. If you want both, your content needs to be a container control like a `StackPanel` that can have multiple contents and you need to put both your `Image` and your `TextBlock` in there.

Example (you need to put in Orientation and Alignment as you see fit):

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,12,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Click="button3_Click"> 
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding Source, ElementName=image1}">
      <Image.BitmapEffect>
        <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="5" />
      </Image.BitmapEffect>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: <Button Content="Blur" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,12,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Click="button3_Click" >
            <Image Source="{Binding Source, ElementName=image1}">
            <Image.BitmapEffect>
            <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="5" />
            </Image.BitmapEffect>
            </Image>
        </Button>

Comment: i did like you sayd and only replaced image source and got the error at </Button> that the property can be set only once and Image Source that the property is set more then once

Comment: @RedDevil please update your question with the exact new source and exact new error message or ask a new question with those two.

Comment: @RedDevil So did I :)

Comment: So i noticed with other effects its the same thing but after i click the effect i notice a small line inside the button under the text of the button like the text is SADASDADADSA and under it is a small blur line.But no matter if i press the button or not i dont see the effect apply.

Comment: managed to make it work from C# rather then XAML by using like this  image1.BitmapEffect = new BevelBitmapEffect();

Comment: so i found out there is a problem with BITMAP Effect and EFFECT and for that reason since 4.0 there is issue with outer glow and some BitmapEffects so i just created my own outer glow from Drop Shadow.Thank you for all your help.